# Making an Access Filter-Macro Based on Text-Field Input

Tags: database, ms-access-2010

I've been wracking my brains on this simple macro for days and troweled almost every site and forum for an answer, to no avail.  Thus, I come to the gurus of stackOverflow for my salvation:

I'm working in Access 2010 and have a database of events that are coming up.  Right now the database opens to a form wherein any user may view the entered events and edit them if there's an error.  Likewise, there's a report that pulls it's list from the form that everyone's working on.

What I'd like to do (for ease of use) is have a text field and a button.  The field would be for date-input (i.e. 10/20/2015) and when pushed, the button would filter the list of events to show only things on or after the typed date.  Likewise, I'm hoping to make another filter for the report that will display items only btw. certain dates (but I'm really just working on the first item).

The concept would look like this:

```
| [ Text Field | [BUTTON]

Event 1 ......................  Date.........
Event 2 ......................  Date.....
....
..
.
```

Note:  This is a database for people who know NOTHING about Access, so I'm trying to spoon-feed the stuff they need to them.

I really appreciate the help, folks.

Comment: Your question is? How to create a report via button in a form?? Why don't you use the same form to display the results, in a listbox for example? We need some more information on what you want to do exactly.